# Is it possible to reference different methods with one method call in a for loop?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

I have a plan to make a GUI as minimal as it gets. I have hit a brick wall where I cant find an answer or maybe some kind of workaround due to me being inexperienced in java.

I have searched quite a bit and only found ways to replace the last letter or number in a string but not in a method call

```java
public static int question;    
public static void main(String[] args) {



int questionNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter project no."));

     if (questionNumber>=7){
         questionNumber=6;
     }
     else if(questionNumber<=3){
         questionNumber=4;
     }
     question = questionNumber;

     System.out.println(question);
     System.out.println(questionNumber);
     for(int i=4; i<=6;i++)
        if(question==i){
          Question4(); // want the number 4 to be the question variable
     }

    }
```

What I would expect is

```java
     for(int i=4; i<=6;i++)
        if(question==i){
          Question *the variable "question" here* (); 
     }
```

and have no idea if that is possible or how to get there.

Comment: Might be possibly in some dynamic languages, but not in a static one such as Java (because what is supposed to happen if the method questionX does not exist?).

Comment: You need a serious of conditionals e.g. `if (i == 4) question4()`. A switch statement can make this less verbose.

Comment: `for(int i=4; i==6;i++)` would loop zero times. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: if you know the question list, you can use the DS (Map) store the answer(Key), question (Value), access the question based on answer from the map

Comment: @Michael you can with reflection.

Comment: @Matthieu shh shh, don't encourage them

Comment: @Michael true XD, I prefer the enum solution, much cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to reference different methods with one method call in
>   a for loop?

Yes.  It depends upon what exactly you mean by *different methods*.  Here are three general ways in which this can be achieved:

- The Java enum facility allows developers to define *constant-specific methods*, which are different method bodies defined in each separate enum constant declaration.  The actual method body that is invoked depends upon the actual enum constant upon which the method call is made (this is actually a specialization of the next bullet item).
- Interfaces enable different method bodies to be defined in each separate implementation.  In this way,  the actual method body that is invoked depends on the instance of the actual implementation upon which the method call is made.
- Another way to invoke different method bodies with "the same method call" is to perform method invocations using Java's Reflection Facility.  Since Java is an Object-oriented development environment, a decision to use reflection should be made carefully.  Reflection is (often much) slower, less readable, and clumsier than solutions that don't use it.  Reflection also makes many errors which could be detected at compile-time detectable at run-time only.

In Java, the principle mechanisms of abstraction are classes and interfaces and, so, when thinking about a problem domain and resolving that into an object domain you should be thinking about how to design interfaces and classes that provide the most natural description possible.

You want to be able to invoke a method that corresponds to a particular question.  A better way to approach this is not to abstract over it with the method call to a question, but to abstract over the questions themselves.  Your project has questions, so this is a good clue that you should have a `Question` class.

Here is a skeletal solution to the problem that makes use of the Java enum facility (enums are a special kind of class).  This solution is similar to the one suggested by Matthieu but it does not need reflection at all; instead it uses the first bullet item above and defines *constant-specific methods* (which is, itself, a specialization of the second bullet item above):

```
public enum Question {
    QUESTION_1 {
        @Override public String getText() {
            return "This is the text for Question #1.";
        }
    },

    QUESTION_2 {
        @Override public String getText() {
            return "This is the text for Question #2.";
        }
    },
    :
    :

    QUESTION_N {
        @Override public String getText() {
            return "This is the text for the final question in the series.";
        }
    };

    public abstract String getText();
}
```

This enum class defines one constant for each question in the series of questions (each of these constant declarations becomes an instance of the enum class `Question` at run-time).  Each declaration defines a different method body for the method `getText()` which is overridden inside each enum constant.

The declaration `public abstract...` at the end of the enum informs the compiler that every enum constant must provide an implementation for the `getText()` method. If a developer adds a new question to the series but forgets to add a `getText()` method in it, the compiler will complain (this is a type of error that can be caught at compile-time with an object-based solution that could only be caught at run-time if reflection were used).

Here is a simple program to exercise your `Question` enum class.  It simply prints out the name of each question constant followed by its question text:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Question question : Question.values()) { // here is the "one for loop"
        String text = question.getText();         // here is the "one method call"
        println(question.toString());
        println(text);
    }
}
```

No reflection is used.  Instead, natural abstraction mechanisms of Java's type system are able to achieve the desired goal of invoking a separate method body for each question.

Answer (score 0):

Using map in this situation is most easiest solution. You should learn how to use them and how they works but, this is more about design now. If you want pass some parameters into your method take a look on Consumer, BiConsumer or even Function class provided by java. Check this example how it could implementation looks with Runnable that takes no parameters.

```java
        Map<Integer, Runnable> map = new HashMap<>(); // creating Map variable
        // registering questions
        map.put(1, () -> {
            System.out.println("Question #1");
        });
        int questionNumber = 0;// get option id
        if (map.containsKey(questionNumber)) { // first check if question is registered
            map.get(questionNumber).run(); // get runnable that is registered with exact questionNumber and run it
        } else {
            // print invalid question number
        }
```

Comment: Add a check for `null` in case the number is not mapped.

Comment: There is no need to null check because accessing variable only if conatinsKey returns true. When you register null variable then you have to check it. I can only recommend not using nulls but rather empty objects that do nothing if needed. Also there is ```else``` statement that handles it.

Comment: True, I didn't see the test just above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-):

```
try {
    Method m =  MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("Question"+questionNum);
    m.invoke(this);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // Handle
}
```

But you should handle the exception properly, because it will most probably fail one day or another.

You can also use an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to define each behavior and call the appropriate:

```
private static enum EnQuestion {
    Question1 {
        public void run(MyClass instance) {
            // ...
        }
    },
    Question2 {
        ...
    },
    ...
    QuestionN {
        ...
    };

    public void run(MyClass instance);
}
```

The enum has to be static so you can't access `MyClass` protected/private fields and methods.

Then call it:

```
EnQuestion.values()[numQuestion].run(this);
```

Comment: *"The enum should be non-static"* ... in Java, all enum classes are implicitly static and final.